# Comprobar que los bits [x:y] sean mayor que un valor n en C

Tags: c

Estoy empezando a aprender la manipulación de bits en C y a lo mejor la pregunta os parece una estupidez pero como puedo comprobar que los bits, a[x:y] sean mayor que un valor n?
Por ejemplo:
Mientras que a[7:4] > 6 { ... }
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes aportar algo de código a tu pregunta? Qué has intentado hacer hasta ahora?

Comment: while( IISFCON[4] > 6 ); Es lo único que puedo aportar como código (Porque es lo único que me piden). También eso es lo único que he intentado porque no se me ocurre otra cosa.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta. Si obligas a la gente a tener que leerse los comentarios para poder contestarte vas a perder atención y respuetas